# Unable to install typings for any language

Tags: typescript-typings

Why I am unable to install ANY typings ??

[image]

[image]

Ok, lets go to https://github.com/typings/typings and see maybe the syntax has changed...

[image]

Ok, there is an example at the bottom:

> typings install dt~angular-component-router

Lets try...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to specify `--global` option as suggested below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify source and use global option (for typings in your example)

```
typings install dt~jquery --global
typings install dt~angular-component-router --global
```

> `dt` - typings from DefinitelyTyped (usually `--global`)